# Getting entire content from table

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I have a table structure like this:

```
id,name,age,etc...
```

I want to get all entries and display them on my website in a table structure, just like they are organized in the MYSQL table itself:

```
| id  | name  | age |
| --- | ----- | --- |
| 1   | Peter | 23  |
| 2   | Susan | 34  |
| 3   | Tom   | 45  |
```

With the following code I can get all names:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "name: "  . $row['name'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
name: Peter
name: Susan
name: Tom
```

But I need to specify each column separately with `$row['name']`. What if there are >100 columns, do I need to specify each of them?

Is there any way to just get all data from my table (incl. all column names) in a JSON response:

```
{"users":[
    {"id":"1", "name":Peter", "age":"23"},
    {"id":"2", "name":"Susan", "age":"34"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"Tom", "age":"45"}
]}
```

Comment: Use `mysql_field_name` to get the column name from db.

Comment: Just a side-note, but you are executing your query twice.

Comment: 100 columns is probably a bad table design

Comment: @jeroen: Thank you, I corrected that.

Comment: @Dagon: I just wanted to point out, that I have many columns and I'm looking for a way to load them, without specifying every name.

Comment: Its much better to specify each, as well as not select *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use something like:

```
 foreach($row as $colName => $colValue)
```

Inside your while loop.

Comment: Thank you, but could you provide a small example, please?

Comment: Of course. Just augment your while loop with something like this:

`while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 foreach($row as $colName => $colValue) {
  echo $colName . ": " . $colValue;
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

> You can use foreach loop like this

```
foreach($result as $column=>$value)
{
   echo $column." : ".$value;
}
```

But the point why are you worrying for 100 columns in a table ? According to normalization, you will not have so many columns in a single table. But even if you have, your column name will not be beautiful to display user because of naming convention like column_name.

Use json_encode to convert to json.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$users=array();
$response=NULL;
if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       $users['users'][]=$row;
    }
   $response=json_encode($users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$all_users = array();
if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    $users = array();$i=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $users[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $users[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $users[$i]['age'] = $row['age'];
        $i++;
    }
}
$all_users['users'] = $users;
echo json_encode($all_users);
```